# How to unset (clear) a TTL value

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, ttl

I have an item in DynamoDB table which has a TTL set to next month.

I want to unset (or clear) the TTL value (so that the item will no longer be scheduled for removal), how do I to it?

---

Here is what I have tried so far, but they both error in my java code:

- I tried setting it to NULL.
- I then tried setting it to a dummy string like "NO VALUE".

---

What is the correct way to unset (clear) a TTL value from an item after the TTL value was previously set.

Comment: Can't you just turn of TTL feature in dynamodb?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/time-to-live-ttl-how-to.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do it is to REMOVE the attribute, as DynamoDB uses a schemaless model, there is no need to set it to "Some empty value" and Number types cannot be Null.

```
aws dynamodb update-item \
    --table-name ProductCatalog \
    --key '{"Id":{"N":"789"}}' \
    --update-expression "REMOVE ttl_attr_name" \
    --return-values ALL_NEW
```

Comment: What if creationTime used for TTL and we want to keep it?

Comment: A) if you want to keep creation time and you use it for TTL, and you only want to disable TTL for some items, I suggest using a different attribute for TTL in your data model. Often users have a stand-alone attribute named `ttl`

Comment: B) if you want to disable TTL for all items, disable it at the table level.